# Can't install mplayer or vlc on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

I am trying to install Mplayer or VLC player on ubuntu feisty but i can't do it. 
I try with apt-get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  mplayer: Depends: libasound2 (> 1.0.16) but 1.0.13-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
           Depends: libavcodec51 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libavcodec-unstripped-51 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not installable
           Depends: libavformat52 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libavformat-unstripped-52 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not installable
           Depends: libavutil49 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libavutil-unstripped-49 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not installable
           Depends: libcaca0 (>= 0.99.beta14-1) but 0.99.beta11.debian-2build1 is to be installed
           Depends: libcdparanoia0 (>= 3.10.2+debian) but 3.10+debian~pre0-4build1 is to be installed
           Depends: libcucul0 (>= 0.99.beta14-1) but 0.99.beta11.debian-2build1 is to be installed
           Depends: libfaad0 (>= 2.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libfribidi0 (>= 0.10.9) but 0.10.7-4build1 is to be installed
           Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.6) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libjack0 (>= 0.109.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: liblzo2-2 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libopenal1 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libpostproc51 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libpostproc-unstripped-51 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not installable
           Depends: libspeex1 (>= 1.2~beta3-1) but 1.1.12-3 is to be installed
           Depends: libsvga1
           Depends: libswscale0 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not going to be installed or
                    libswscale-unstripped-0 (>= 0.svn20080206-8) but it is not installable
           Depends: mplayer-skin
  python-apt: Depends: libapt-inst-libc6.7-6-1.1
              Depends: libapt-pkg-libc6.7-6-4.6
  scim-gtk2-immodule: Depends: libscim8c2a (>= 1.4.6) but 1.4.4-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
  scim-modules-socket: Depends: libscim8c2a (>= 1.4.6) but 1.4.4-7ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I try apt-get -f install but it doesn't work neither. What to do please help me ?!

Comment: I think you should provide your /etc/apt/source.list

Comment: could you try sudo apt-get update ?

Answer (score 2):

If this didn't help and you still getting an error:

> The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies.   mplayer: Depends:
>   mplayer-nogui but it is not going to
>   be installed
>              Depends: libvdpau1 but it is not installable E: Broken packages

Try to install these packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mplayer-nogui
```

> The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies.   mplayer-nogui:
>   Depends: libvdpau1 but it is not
>   installable E: Broken packages

And again:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libvdpau1
```

> Package libvdpau1 is not available,
>   but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is
>   missing, has been obsoleted, or is
>   only available from another source E:
>   Package libvdpau1 has no installation
>   candidate $

Ah-ha, gotcha! The issue is fixed by adding:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc-svn/ppa/ubuntu $your_distro main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc-svn/ppa/ubuntu $your_distro main
```

to the  `/etc/apt/source.list` and running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you might have an invalid /etc/apt/sources.list file.  Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, try installing VLC again.